# Is it legal to create my own recording of a call on a KNOWN State-recorded Court line?

Tags: california, recording

Long story short, I received my first speeding ticket despite the fact that I was indeed, NOT speeding.

I chose to submit everything in writing, as that was a choice made by the Court. I had an online chat with a Court Clerk through the County of Riverside website, and took a screenshot of the chat where I was informed by a Court employee that my information and payment could be POSTMARKED ON OR BEFORE THE DUE DATE and I would not get penalized.

I knew they would screw with me (which they DID), so I also CALLED the Court, and was on a recorded line (the standard "this call may be recorded for training and quality service), so I also recorded the call myself, and again asked the court clerk the same question about having the fine POSTMARKED on or before the due date,and I received the same answer.

Of course thanks to USPS being lame, the mail that should have arrived within two days (it traveled a whopping 40 miles) arrived late, but was postmarked in a timely manner.  The power-tripper at the court told me that she was sending the whopping $23 to COLLECTIONS and that my tax refund would be withheld over the $23 fee (the bank erroneously thought my ticket fee was a fraudulent charge on my credit card as I previously had issues with fraudulent charges.  I contacted the bank, and the payment went through, and I was still charged $23 (which also cleared).

So since i emailed a copy of the screenshot and the audio recording proving that I shouldn't be oenalized for the $23 being late, will I NOW get into trouble for "illegally recording" the clerk, despite being notified that the call was being recorded by the Court?

Comment: what state is this?

Comment: @jesse_b California

Comment: It is widely understood that legal communications of that sort are "submitted” on the date they are postmarked. There was no reason for you to have recorded the conversation.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that there was a cheque or other payment that was sent on time and arrived after the date? And this cheque payment bounced?

Comment: California is a two party consent state for recording so they had your consent to record but you did not have their consent to perform your own recording.

Comment: @jesse_b, Do you have a reference to a law that says both parties must consent to each copy made by separate parties?  I believe that it has been asked and answered here that consent by both parties constitutes consent for either side to record.  If you have such a reference please post it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHall California penal code § 632 states "A person who, intentionally and without the consent of all parties to a confidential communication, uses an electronic amplifying or recording device to eavesdrop upon or record the confidential communication" -- The court clerk had consent to record but OP did not.

Comment: @jesse_b, but that doesn't specifically say what you are interpreting that it does.  The court clerk has consented to their being recorded by stating to the OP that the conversation is being recorded.  Consider that consent can be made by non response to a statement that the call is being recorded.  You don't have to actually even ask for permission.

Comment: @MichaelHall I wouldn't be surprised if it was interpreted your way and I also wouldn't be surprised if it were interpreted my way.  IMO logically though my way makes more sense.  My consent for ME to make a recording should not imply that I also consent for YOU to make a recording.  If you have a nest camera in your house and ask guests to consent to being recorded does that implicitly give them permission to also record you?

Comment: @MichaelHall also to your point of non response being consent, in that example it is still a requirement that the person who is performing the recording inform all parties that they are recording.